# how to store and retrieve a function?

Tags: python

I am new to python and originally from C and I am not able to figure out the function pointer and callbacks equivalent in python.

I am doing the below but don't know why I get an error and none ? :

```
def a():
    print "a"

def b():
    print "b"

def c():
    print "c"

def d():
    print "d"

# Build dummy table    
sm = [ [ a , b ], [ c, d ] ]

print sm[0][1]() # Name error sm not defined. --??
```

Result is :

```
b # This is expected
None
```

Why is name error and why am i getting None ? How do i create a table and store some functions in python?

Comment: Your comments say "Name error", but your results show no such thing, and your results are pretty much exactly what I'd expect. What's wrong? The `None`? You'd get that even if you just did `print d()`, since you've forgotten which code's responsibility it is to do the printing.

Comment: by default any function that lack a `return`, will return `None`, so as defined here all your functions `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will print something and return `None` then that result is picked by the print in the line `print sm[0][1]()` and, well, printed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are printing the variable inside the function `b()`.  `print` returns `None` so the outer print statement is printing "None."  All the `prints` in the functions should be returns.

Comment: thanks. but what is the name error ?

Comment: May be its the problem with the pycharm ?

Comment: I am not getting that when I reproduce is in the python interpreter.  So not sure.

Comment: thanks. then its the problem of pycharm

Comment: Are you sure `print` returns `none`?

Comment: @intboolstring Well, technically it doesn't return anything but Python treats that as None. Since there's no return, it's moot - the None is actually coming from the method itself not returning, rather than returning the result of `print()`

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing `return` and `print`.

### Return

The return value goes into the expression.

For example:

```
def b():
    return 7
7*b() #prints 49
```

### Print

Prints output to a console

```
def b():
    print "Hello World"
b() #Prints Hello World!
```

If you try

```
def b():
    print "3"
b()*2
```

That is invalid syntax.

### Together

```
def b():
    print "10"
    return 7
print b()*5 #prints 35 because 7*5
```

**A python function has a default return value of `None`, so if you don't return anything, that will be returned.  That is how you are seeing `None`.**